# Kinect v2 sensor Color-Depth Mapping misalignment using matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect, matlab-cvst, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

so I am performing a mapping of depth frame into the color space using rotation and translation values I obtained during calibration

So below are the results:[image]

In this image the mapping is gud; however, a couple of frames down the video, here is the result; using the same parameters:

[image]

As you can see, the wall depth pixels are getting mixed with the head pixels by quite a significant amount.

Does anyone know why is that? Parallax error maybe?

Comment: Could you explain what we are seeing? I am unable to read the depth information in the images.

Comment: @Daniel Okay so the above image has two figures overlayed ontop of each other. The one with the small squares is the depth data mapped ontop the colorspace or colorcamera. So comparing the first image and the second image, in the first one, you can see that the small squares follow the head contours properly however in the second one, theres this overlap of pixels which shld be representing the wall onto the head